# Webscraping from a dynamic website without using selenium/headless browser

Tags: python, multithreading, pool

I am trying to scrape data from this site .On printing the request content it is giving me error "Please enable js and disable any ad blocker" .I tried to to add header/fake agent but same above issue is coming.
import requests
url = "https://www.carsales.com.au/cars/private/used/australian-capital-territory-state/?sort=LastUpdated"
htmlContent = requests.get(url)
print(htmlContent)
print(htmlContent.text)

I dont want to use selenium to scrap the dynamic data .Can you please guide and alternative way.

Thanks in advance.